# Beep ×11? Computer beep when booting

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

This is an issue which is happening me with a computer having [Asrock 939A8X-M](http://www.asrock.com/mb/ULi/939A8X-M/) motherboard.

When it is all complete (with everything connected) the fans do start but the rest of the components seem dead and it is not making any noise at all.

When I remove the GPU though, the PC starts beeping which I guess it is a good signal to make a problem diagnosis.
Well, here's the beeping sound https://soundcloud.com/user102707346/beep#t=0:30

It seems like it is beeping 11 times, cannot tell for sure because the first beep can seem either one or two.

If it was just one, it would be 11 beeps, which according to [this](http://acronymsonline.com/lists/beep_chart.asp) site should be a processor cache issue and I would have to replace that component.

> 11 Beeps - Cache Memory Bad

Now where I'd like to get help at, is the sound really 11 beeps and so is it a cache error? Did I miss something during the diagnosing process before replacing that component?

Answer (score 0):

A PC cannot boot without a GPU, memory, processor and obviously power. If any of these are not present (I'll ignore the power for obvious reasons) the pc will start to beep.

Given that you removed the GPU, it is obvious that it'll beep unless you have an onboard additional GPU.

The error beeps are specific for each motherboard, and you'll have to refer to the manual to find out what the beeps mean.

So you'll have to diagnose differently. If you want to be sure that the GPU is not dead, place the GPU in a different pc and power it up. If the PC starts up, the GPU is not dead.

Alternatively, get a GPU from another pc and insert it into yours and see if your pc will boot. If your pc suddenly boots, insert back your old GPU and see if it stops booting again or suddenly boots again too. Sometimes a loose cable can cause for this. Use these techniques to verify that everything works, including testing the monitor.

It is hard to do this with your CPU, so keep this as a last effort. Note that an improperly seated heatsink on the CPU will give the exact same symptoms. The fans start going, but nothing happens. Same as for improperly seated memory, or GPU.